# Смена кодировки через servlet фильтр

Tags: java, servlet, utf-8, фильтры

Класс сервлета:

```
package ru.javavision.servlet;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;


public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {
@Override
public void init() throws ServletException {

}

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/view/index.jsp").forward(req, resp);
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    final String data = req.getParameter("data");
    resp.getWriter().write(data);
}
}
```

Фильтр:

```
package ru.javavision.servlet;

import javax.servlet.*;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Filter implements javax.servlet.Filter {
    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        servletRequest.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        servletResponse.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }
}
```

index.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="post" action="/" >
    <input type="text" name="data">
    <input type="submit" name="Отправить">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

и web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
<filter>
    <filter-name>Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>ru.javavision.servlet.Filter</filter-class>
</filter>
    <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>Filter</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Serv</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>ru.javavision.servlet.Servlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Serv</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Проверял, фильтр запускается, но при вводе русских символов в форму кодировка не срабатывает.Подскажите в чем может быть проблема.

Comment: В html коде должна быть задана кодировка, [пример](http://htmlbook.ru/html/meta/charset) .  `filter-mapping.url-pattern` должен быть не `/` а `/*` .

Comment: Уже пробовал - не работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ: 
В doFilter надо добавить

`servletResponse.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");`

Answer (score 1):

Вот это 100% рабочий фильтр:

```
    import javax.servlet.Filter;
    import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
    import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
    import java.io.IOException;

    public class CharsetFilter implements Filter {
        // кодировка
        private String encoding;

        public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
            // читаем из конфигурации
            encoding = config.getInitParameter("requestEncoding");

            // если не установлена — устанавливаем UTF-8
            if (encoding == null) encoding = "UTF-8";
        }

        public void doFilter(ServletRequest request,
                             ServletResponse response, FilterChain next)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
            request.setCharacterEncoding(encoding);
            next.doFilter(request, response);
        }

        public void destroy() {
        }
    }
```

Comment: Вопросительные знаки вместо символов